# What is the meaning of this "Navigational Warning" and does it apply to the aviation industry?

Tags: navigation, airspace

*This was posted at https://sattrackcam.blogspot.com/2021/09/an-upcoming-trident-ii-d5-slbm-test-in.html*

Th blog post notes something as a "navigational warning".

> A few days ago a **Navigational Warning (NAVAREA IV 838/21, also
> issued as HYDROLANT 2336/21)** appeared

And it says that the warning mapped to a upcoming missile test. (check the link)

The text is this:

> ```
> 151459Z SEP 21
> NAVAREA IV 838/21(11,24,26).
> ATLANTIC OCEAN.
> FLORIDA.
>
> 1. HAZARDOUS OPERATIONS 171230Z THRU 200123Z SEP
>    IN AREAS BOUND BY:
>
>    A. 28-56N 079-59W, 29-02N 079-53W,
>       29-06N 079-37W, 28-59N 079-10W,
>       28-37N 079-10W, 28-36N 079-35W,
>       28-45N 079-56W.             
>
>    B. 28-24N 076-44W, 28-42N 076-42W,
>       28-21N 074-40W, 28-06N 074-44W.
>
>    C. 27-27N 071-21W, 27-52N 071-15W,
>       27-25N 068-46W, 26-54N 068-54W.
>
>    D. 17-22N 044-54W, 18-33N 044-32W,
>       16-54N 040-55W, 16-00N 041-23W.
>    
>    E. 09-00S 003-51W, 08-22S 003-22W,
>       12-35S 002-40E, 13-05S 002-19E,
>       11-56S 000-16E, 12-09S 000-16W,
>       11-34S 000-20W.
>
> 2. CANCEL THIS MSG 200223Z SEP 21.
> ```

Is this a threat to planes? Do pilots and/or other relevant bodies consider this?

Comment: Given that there's **no altitude information,** and the first answer quoting *only* boats, this isn't about aviation. I'm voting to close for being off-topic.

Comment: @ymb1  _for people sailing or flying in that part of the world._ read the answer.

Comment: @ymb1 you are saying that this is offtopic? : _is this a threat to planes? Do pilots and/or other relevant bodies consider this?_ also threats doesn't need to have altitude information such as terrorists with arms.

Comment: **"Navigational Warnings** In support of the Global **Maritime** Distress and Safety System (GMDSS), Broadcast Warnings are promulgated by the Worldwide Navigational Warnings Service (WWNWS) to provide rapid dissemination of information critical to navigation and **the safety of life at sea."** [1](https://msi.nga.mil/NavWarnings) – The answer inferred flying, but did **not** quote flying. A simple search would have shown this is ***not*** used by aviation bodies.

Comment: @ymb1 It is the warning, I specifically asked the pilots do they consider it. I removed the parts which will be off-topic because only now I know it is for maritime.

Comment: Why would pilots or aviation bodies use maritime messages? Plus the question title says something else.

Comment: @ymb1 _Why would_ that's what I am asking. _why_ part comes part _do_.

Comment: **Where** does it say it's used by pilots? If it did, then sure, *why would* be valid.

Comment: @ymb1 _does it say it's used by pilots_ I don't say it is used, that's why I asked *do they*.

Comment: Your original question was "What is the meaning of this text? what paths are dangerous? what is a Navigational Warning?" Come on. Sure you can pivot it if you want, **after knowing it's maritime only,** but does not make it on-topic here. And the edit invalidates the answer, which is not acceptable here.

Comment: A better on-topic question would be: How (if at all) are pilots warned of ICBM tests? **But** you have to limit it to a country, because as the recent news show, North Korea, for example, doesn't care and pilots are warned by neighboring countries mid-air.

Comment: To be clear - neither I or, nor any other pilots I know, reference the Navigational Warnings promulgated by WWNWS. This is the first I've ever heard of them. It is standard for pilots to reference TFRs and NOTAMS, with other lookups based on where you're going. TFRs and NOTAMS *do* cover missile launches, like the one you referenced.

Comment: @ymb1 If it wasn't for the _edit invalidates the answer_ I might have written a lengthy Meta post Why some of you are illusion-ed in the matter of offtopic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a warning for people sailing or flying in that part of the world. Google [says](https://www.google.com/search?q=navigational%20warning&oq=navigational%20warning&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.3280j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8):

> Navigational warnings (NAVWARNs) contain information for boaters about
> changes to navigational aids and current marine activities or hazards,
> such as: defects. dredging.

The latitude and longitude points will show you exactly where expected danger is expected to occur. It has a map in the article you linked - what else would you like to know about what parts are dangerous?

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: Where does google say about flying?

Comment: Google didn't say anything about flying, but if there were an ICBM test I certainly wouldn't fly inside those boxes.

Comment: "*Google says [...]*": To be fair with the content author, it's not Google which says that, but the Maritime Safety Office, https://msi.nga.mil/NavWarnings. Google just cites it.

Comment: There might be a corresponding NOTAM -- notice to airmen, which warns fliers to avoid this area.  It also might be inside a published warning area, which would simply "go hot" around the time of the launch.  So there are ways that pilots get this sort of info, but the document in the OP is ***not*** it.